# Meu código para o enigma das jarras não está funcionando

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

Em primeiro lugar, quero agradecer todos os que lerem esse meu pedido de ajuda. Sou bem novato na linguagem C e tenho mais que certeza que errei e não foi pouco nesse código. Passei o dia todo me empenhando em escrevê-lo mas não consigo achar o erro. Creio que seja algum uso inadequado de ponteiros na função swap() ou alguma outra coisa boba que eu fiz. Enfim, aí está. Por favor, perdoem as noobagens, fiz tudo com meu melhor. O programa até aceita alguns movimentos, mas a maioria não. Estou a utilizar o Ubuntu na sua última versão.

Edit1: O problema das jarras é o seguinte:
Você tem três jarras numa mesa a sua frente. A primeira comporta três litros, a segunda cinco litros e a última, comporta oito, e é a única que está cheia. Seu objetivo é separar quatro litros nas jarras b e c, e o único movimento que você pode fazer é o de trocar o líquido de uma jarra para a outra, até que ela atinja o limite da jarra que recebe, ou até o líquido da jarra que despeja acabar.

Edit2: Fiz algumas pequenas modificações e o programa acerta algumas respostas com precisão, por exemplo:

```
State:
a = 0, b = 0, c = 8
>3 1
State:
a = 3, b = 0, c = 5
```

Porém transferir de c para b não retorna o esperado:

```
State:
a = 3, b = 0, c = 5
>3 2
State:
a = 3, b = 3, c = 2
```

Obrigado desde já.

Edit3: Código comentado para melhor compreensão.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define MAXA 3 //Defino o maximo da variável a, e etc;
#define MAXB 5
#define MAXC 8

int a = 0, b = 0, c = 8; //Defino que só a terceira está cheia.
void swap(int *po, int *pd) //Função de troca, aceita dois ponteiros para inteiros,
{                           // Mas não sei se estou a usar corretamente;
  int maxor, maxdes; //Defino duas variáveis que comportarão o máximo da origem e destino.
  if(po != &a && po != &b && po != &c || pd != &a && pd != &b && pd != &c || po == pd) //Caso for inválido,
    return; //quebre.
  if(po == &a) //Se o ponteiro recebido apontar para a, máximo da origem é MAXA, etc...
    maxor = MAXA;
  if(po == &b)
    maxor = MAXB;
  if(po == &c)
    maxor == MAXC;
  if(pd == &a)
    maxdes = MAXA;
  if(pd == &b)
    maxdes == MAXB;
  if(pd == &c)
    maxdes == MAXC;
  int d = maxdes - *pd; //Variável que define o quanto o destino comporta, e o quanto a origem fornecerá.
  *pd += d;
  *po -= d;

}
int main()
{
  int *pa = &a; //Defino os ponteiros para as respectivas variáveis.
  int *pb = &b;
  int *pc = &c;
  while(b != 4 && c != 4) //Enquanto não houver quatro litros em b e c;
  {
    int (*alfa), (*beta); //Ponteiros que eventualmente apontarão pra escolha do usuário.
    int cho, chos; //Inteiros de escolha de origem e destino.
    printf("State:\na = %i, b = %i, c = %i\n>", a, b, c); //Imprime o estado atual.
    scanf("%i %i", &cho, &chos);
    if(cho == 1) //Caso cho seja 1, o ponteiro alfa aponta para a, e etc.
      alfa = &a;
    if(cho == 2)
      alfa = &b;
    if(cho == 3)
      alfa = &c;
    if(chos == 1)
      beta = &a;
    if(chos == 2)
      beta = &b;
    if(chos == 3)
      beta = &c;
    swap(alfa, beta); //Realize a troca entre alfa e beta;
  }
}
```

Comment: Em sua função swap, primeiro if, você quer mesmo comparar o endereço das variáveis? Não vejo sentido nisso, creio que deveria comparar o conteúdo destas variáveis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que seu programa poderia ter muitas de suas características re-pensadas, como a necessidade de ter variáveis globais e a necessidade de fazer uso de tantos ponteiros, visto que existem apenas três potes. Porém, não vou tratar disso na resposta, visto que você pediu para tal.
O problema principal pode ser corrigido apenas olhando os warnings que o compilador retorna (preferencialmente compilando com a opção `-Wall`). Embora tenha sido mais de um, vou omitir os semelhantes, sobrando os da seguinte forma:

```
testeC.c:19:11: warning: equality comparison result unused [-Wunused-comparison]
    maxor == MAXC;
    ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
testeC.c:12:27: warning: '&&' within '||' [-Wlogical-op-parentheses]
  if(po != &a && po != &b && po != &c || pd != &a && pd != &b && pd != &c || po == pd) //Caso for inválido,
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~ ~
```

O primeiro warning mostra que você se confundiu o operador de atribuição =, com o operador de comparação ==. Em algumas linhas você utilizou `maxor==MAX_` quando deveria ter utilizado `maxor=MAX_`. Este é o caso das linhas 19, 23 e 25.

Além disso, o outro warning te alerta sobre algo que deve sempre ser feito no caso de if's lógicos como o seu. Você deve sempre utilizar parênteses para explicitar ao compilador a ordem que você quer que ele realize as operações. Na dúvida sobre a precedência dos operadores, minha sugestão é pecar pelo exagero e pela leitura facilitada do código.
Com essas modificações o código parece funcionar:

```
State:
a = 0, b = 0, c = 8
>3 1
State:
a = 3, b = 0, c = 5
>3 2
State:
a = 3, b = 5, c = 0
```

Por último, acredito que você esqueceu de verificar no final da função swap, se o jarro de origem possui conteúdo suficiente para fazer a transição. Você verifica apenas a capacidade no destino. Isso gera o seguinte engano:

```
State:
a = 0, b = 0, c = 8
>3 1
State:
a = 3, b = 0, c = 5
>3 2
State:
a = 3, b = 5, c = 0
>1 3
State:
a = -5, b = 5, c = 8
```

Como foram poucas modificações, acredito não ser necessário re-colocar o código completo aqui, mas se você precisar ou tiver alguma dúvida adicional basta pedir.

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora está funcionando perfeitamente.

Comment: De nada! Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita, para a pergunta ficar como resolvida, e ajudar eventuais buscas no site.